# How to get a usable ${callsite} using nlog and asp.net core rc2

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, nlog

I'm using NLog with asp.net core rc2. ("NLog.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc2-final-2016-05-21") I'm having difficulty getting the location of the logging event using the ${callsite} tag in the layout.  I prefer this to typing it in the message because I want to render it to its own database column.

My startup looks like this:

```
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddNLog();
        env.ConfigureNLog("NLog.config");
```

My NLog configuration:

```
<target xsi:type="File" name="infolog" fileName="${basedir}/logs/info-${shortdate}.log"
        layout="${longdate}|${level}|${callsite:className=true:methodName=true}|${machinename}|${message}" />
```

called like this:

```
Logger.LogInformation("Information: User > Get");
```

Alas, the output is always:

```
2016-06-20 16:00:03.4458|Info|Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Logger.Log ...
```

Is there a way using the Microsoft logging extensions and NLog to get the class/method name where the log was written?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution.
Update the package to the lastest, 1.0.0-rtm-alpha3

Check the dependencies.  If you see 4.3.4, you need to tweak it.
[image]

1. Find the package .nuspec file.

[image]

2. Open the file in Notepad.
3. Edit the file, and change the NLog version to 4.3.5
   [image]
4. Restore packages.  This will update the dependency in your project.  It should work as expected now.

Answer (score 2):

I just had that problem using Owin + NLog and I found out that you need to tell NLog to "**ignore**" those *logging wrappers*, that can be done by using **LogManager.AddHiddenAssembly**, in my case I just had to add this to my Startup class:

```
LogManager.AddHiddenAssembly(typeof(NLogFactory).Assembly);
LogManager.AddHiddenAssembly(typeof(LoggerExtensions).Assembly);
```

In your case, I think it should be:

```
LogManager.AddHiddenAssembly(typeof(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Logger.Log).Assembly);
```

I haven't tested it, but it can point you to the right direction.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is marked as a bug over on GitHub.
I tried various variations on 
`LogManager.AddHiddenAssembly(typeof(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerFactory).Assembly);`
but had no luck.

Comment: @Elton It looks like this answer solved the problem in the GitHub issue(https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/1512)? Did it not?

Comment: It may have.  I've been working on other things and haven't been in that project in a while.